# How to extend master to include rebased feature branch?

Tags: git

I'm certain this is a duplicate, but I cannot find the original.

I have a local feature branch that is on top of the local master:

```
 master    feature
     |     |
--A--B--C--D
```

Now i just want to update the master branch by the feature branch so that I have:

```
           master
           feature
           |
--A--B--C--D
```

Basically I want to shoft the master label to be at the place of the feature branch label. How can I do that?

Comment: This is called a "fast-forward merge"; searching for that may find you what you need.

Comment: Are you looking to do this locally, or on the remote repo (GitHub, Bitbucket, etc.) ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen locally

Comment: Just merging feature into master should be enough, I reckon.  You could also do, from master, `git reset --hard feature`, in this particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple merge, so all you have to do is

```sh
git checkout master # you can ignore if you're already on master
git merge feature
```

That's basically it. It will do a fast-forward merge given you don't have any commit on master.